# Wrong arguments count in next function calls

Tags: linux, shell, ksh, aix

I've got function ShowJobHistory, and it's called from another. At first call of this function everything works fine, it count proper number of arguments, parse them as  I want to. But in next calls, even if I specify a multiple arguments, this function treat them as one, and it looks ( jb.RJBGID=12871 12873 12868 ) after parsing them. What's wrong with my function?

```bsh
ShowJobHistory () {
conditions=
argCount=$#
if [[ $argCount -ne 0 ]] then
    if [[ $1 == [iI] && $argCount -eq 3 ]] then
        if [[ $2 -lt $3 ]] then
            conditions="( jb.RJBGID between $2 and $3 )"
        else
            conditions="( jb.RJBGID between $3 and $2 )"
        fi
    else
        conditions="("
        for nr in $@
        do
            conditions="${conditions} jb.RJBGID=${nr} or "
        done
        conditions=${conditions%or }
        conditions=$conditions")"
    fi

    typeset query
```

Below function calls ShowJobHistory.

```
ShowJobHistoryMenu () {
typeset jobID
save=
echo "Enter jobIDs" 
read jobID?"Enter jobID: "  
while [[ $save != [nNyY] ]]
do
    read save?"Save output to file? [y/n]"
done
if [[ save = [yY] ]] then
    ShowJobHistory $jobID | tee $TRACEDIR/output.txt
else
    ShowJobHistory $jobID
fi
}
```

Comment: What is your input, what is the output you are getting and what is the expected output?

Comment: Arguments for this function are eneterd by the user, parsed arguments are sql where statement, and I've getting sql error as unexpected output in case of sql query results.

Comment: `( jb.RJBGID=12871 12873 12868 ) after parsing them.` At which point of script code did you print that?

Comment: It's shows as an part of error in sql query, but it will be printed after the if condition. printing `$#` shows 1, even if a wrote a few arguments, for example: 12871 12873 12868

Comment: You may try writing a loop through all the arguments using $@ and updating the `argCount`(similar to what you have done for `nr`) Check to see if its really getting those arguments intended.

Comment: First call of ShowJobHistoryMenu -> ShowJobHistory:
`Enter jobID: 12871 12873;
arguments count: 2;
( jb.RJBGID=12871 or jb.RJBGID=12873 );`

Another calls: 
`Enter jobID: 12871 12873;
arguments count: 1;
( jb.RJBGID=12871 12873 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `IFS=" "` in your shell script and check if the problem is fixed.

Else try this workaround:

```
for nr in `echo $@` [[ Similar to: for nr in $@ ]]
do
   conditions="${conditions} jb.RJBGID=${nr} or "
done
```

Else this:

```
set -A array $@
for nr in `echo ${array[@]}` [[ Similar to: for nr in ${array[@]} ]]
do
  conditions="${conditions} jb.RJBGID=${nr} or "
done
```

To get the total no. of elements in the array you can use: `echo ${#array[@]}`
And remember to `unset array` before using the array again(Although `set -A array` will do that every time its called, just to be safer).

Try all the solutions given above, let me know if there's still some unresolved problems.

Comment: The `echo` in backticks is not only Useless, it is horrendously wrong in this case. You want `for nr in "$@"`.

Comment: Thanks, set arguments to array works for me. But i'm still curious, why it recognize list of arguments as one in next this same function calls.

Comment: There's a lot many reasons why that wouldn't work. The IFS(Input Field Separator) is the most important thing that needs to be set to make $@,$*,etc. to work properly. If that doesn't help, then there's something else which is impacting the code flow.

Comment: OK, I found the reason why it didn't work. Later in the code I've change the value of IFS to set another array, so it has the previous value. I make some changes in code, and now IFS is reset to it's default value at function end. Thanks a lot for solution and tips.

Comment: Repeat; you need to double-quote `$@` - any other use is incorrect.

Comment: Agreed about enclosing special parameters, `$@` in double quotes.

Comment: The purpose of `$@` is to preserve whitespace and special characters in the argument list, but even then it only works correctly when double-quoted. If you use `\`echo "$@"\`` you will again lose any significant whitespace, and waste a useless fork. Generally speaking, `echo` in backticks is usually Useless. See further http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#echo